# django and morris.js charts: not displaying the chart

Tags: django, morris.js

I am trying to use a morris chart in django. I have the following code but it doesn't display the chart when I load the page.

```
  var bar = new Morris.Bar({
  element: 'bar-chart',
  resize: true,
  data: [
    {% for item in data %}
{ period: '{{ item.period }}', addition: '{{ item.addition }}', depreciation: '{{ item.depreciation }}' }{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  ],
  barColors: ['#00a65a', '#f56954'],
  xkey: 'period',
  ykeys: ['addition', 'depreciation'],
  labels: ['Addition', 'Depreciation'],
  hideHover: 'auto'
});
```

This is what I have in my django view:

```
def index(request):

mydata = []
mydata = ADRAnalysis.objects.values_list('period', 'addition', 'depreciation').filter(period__in=['Jan-2016', 'Feb-2016', 'Mar-2016'])

return render(request, 'app/index.html', {'data': mydata,})
```

In Python, I am getting the data:

```
>>> mydata
<QuerySet [('Jan-2016', 110.01, 50.74), ('Feb-2016', 235.16, 50.33), ('Mar-2016', 117.74, 52.63)]>
>>>
```

I am not sure why it's not loading the data. Can someone help pointing out what I am doing wrong or how it should be properly done?